# Node.js - Delete Azure blob

Tags: node.js, json, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to get a list of names only from an azure blob container with the following method. The aim is to pass an array to different methods which delete, download etc.

```
listContainerBlobs = async (blobDirName) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        const blobService = azureStorage.createBlobService(azureStorageConfig.accountName, azureStorageConfig.accountKey); 
        blobService.listBlobsSegmentedWithPrefix(`${azureStorageConfig.containerName}`, `${blobDirName}`, null, (err, data) => {    
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                var blobsArr = [];
                var blobsJSON = data.entries;
                for(var i = 0; i < blobsJSON.length; i++){
                    for(name in blobsJSON[i]){
                        if (blobsJSON[i] == "name") {
                            blobsArr.push(blobsJSON[i][key]);   
                        }
                      }
                }
                resolve(
                {
                    blobsArr
                });
            }
        });
    });
};
```

blobsArr is always returned empty.

Below is the JSON returned by blobsJSON:

```
{
    "blobsJSON": [
        {
            "name": "WKRVAR000241/site_inst_files/avatar002.png",
            "creationTime": "Tue, 16 Jul 2019 22:49:22 GMT",
            "lastModified": "Tue, 16 Jul 2019 22:49:22 GMT",
            "etag": "0x8D70A3FD83B30DA",
            "contentLength": "5309",
            "contentSettings": {
                "contentType": "image/png",
                "contentEncoding": "",
                "contentLanguage": "",
                "contentMD5": "F1CkPOwHPwTMDf6a3t1yCg==",
                "cacheControl": "",
                "contentDisposition": ""
            },
            "blobType": "BlockBlob",
            "accessTier": "Hot",
            "accessTierInferred": true,
            "lease": {
                "status": "unlocked",
                "state": "available"
            },
            "serverEncrypted": "true"
        }
    ]
}
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong. I need to return a list of values for the name key only.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        for(var i = 0; i < blobsJSON.length; i++){
            for(name in blobsJSON[i]){
                if (blobsJSON[i] == "name") {
                    blobsArr.push(blobsJSON[i][key]);   
                }
              }
        }
```

Update above to:

```
        for(var i = 0; i < blobsJSON.length; i++){
            blobsArr.push(blobsJSON[i].name);   
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a sample for you, there are two XML files in a virtual directory `xml` of the container `test` of my Azure Blob Storage, as the figure below.

[image]

If your expected result is `[ 'xml/A.xml', 'xml/B.xml' ]`, you just need to use the [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to get the list from `data.entries` as the code below.

```
data.entries.map(entry => entry.name)
```

Here is my complete sample code.

```
var azure = require('azure-storage');
const accountName = '<your account name>';
const accountKey = 'your account key';
const blobService = azure.createBlobService(accountName, accountKey);

const containerName = 'test';

listContainerBlobs = async (blobDirName) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        //const blobService = azureStorage.createBlobService(azureStorageConfig.accountName, azureStorageConfig.accountKey); 
        blobService.listBlobsSegmentedWithPrefix(`${containerName}`, `${blobDirName}`, null, (err, data) => {    
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(data.entries.map(entry => entry.name))
            }
        });
    });
};

(async() => {
    blobs = await listContainerBlobs('xml/');
    console.log(blobs)
})();
```

The screenshot of the result is below.

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Peter Pan, that helps and seems a cleaner way to do it. Appreciate you taking the time to provide this.